# Windows 7 printing to OSX print server

Tags: windows-7, mac-osx, printing, print-server

I have a OSX Leopard desktop with a USB Canon Printer (MX310).  Apple's instructions state that to share this to Windows machines, they need to have a Postscript driver. I've tried the Adobe one recommended, but it won't install in Windows 7.

I've tried using Bonjour, but it won't bring up the correct Canon driver and I suspect I need Postscript anyway.

Has anyone else gotten this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Is SMB File sharing enabled on the Leopard desktop? System Preferences > Sharing > Options...

It's kind of confusing how it just states "files and folders", but the printers are also shared using SMB.

Then navigate to the leopard desktop in windows (Start > Run > "\\computername.local" or "\\ipaddress"), and the printer should show. I'm not sure about what driver to use, but i've loaded standard PCL drivers in the past with success.